# Setting data source for reports in Crystal Reports 2008 Java (performance)

Tags: java, crystal-reports, datasource

we have Crystal Reports 2008 on the Tomcat 5.5 server, and use the Java SDK to display reports and convert them to PDF.

Since the server has its own database, we have to set the data source on the DatabaseController to make CR connect to this database. We do it like specified in the docs, and tried the functions in CRJavaHelper, but for a reason unknown to me setting the connection string takes 300ms to 1500ms.

What is the fastest way to tell Crystal which datasource to use in its reports? I already saw a JNDI name somewhere, but i don't believe CR actually does a JNDI lookup to find an existing datasource, doesn't it? I haven't worked with JNDI datasources before, should I use them instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this out for myself. By Adding a DataSource to the `context.xml` of the web app and by referencing it in `web.xml`, Crystal then happily uses it. This is the fastest way to do it.